# How can i do dynamically detect the path of mysqldump at linux server from window with java?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I try backup from remote server at  java but it not work .It can't call  mysqldump path .I don't know how to call mysqldump  path from remote linux server.How can i do dynamically detect the path of linux server mysqldump from window?like that "\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\"?Pls anyone help me .

```
public class db {

    public static void main (String arg[])
    {       
          String path = "C:/thiri.sql";
          String username = "devadmin";
          String password = "root";
          String dbname = "mydb";
          String hostip="192.168.4.205";
          String port="3306";
          String mySQlPath = "/usr/bin/mysqldump";//sqldump path from Linux 
          String executeCmd = mySQlPath +" -h "+ hostip +" -P "+ port +" -u  " +username + " -p" + password + " --add-drop-database -B " + dbname + " -r " + path;
          Process runtimeProcess;
          try {
    //          System.out.println(executeCmd);//this out put works in mysql shell
     //         runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "cmd.exe", "/c", executeCmd });
              runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
              int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

              if (processComplete == 0) {
                  System.out.println("Backup created successfully");

              } else {
                  System.out.println("Could not create the backup");
              }
          } catch (Exception ex) {
              ex.printStackTrace();
          }
    }

}
```

Comment: I would think that the path containing spaces may confuse the system. Try to enclose it in `\"`.

Comment: @UweAllner - that won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably to do with spaces in the pathname, and `exec`'s inability to handle this.

(Seriously ... `exec(String)` does not understand the difference between a space between arguments and a space in a pathname.  And it doesn't understand quoting, so adding quotes will only make matters worse.  Read the javadocs!)

The solution is to use the `exec(String[])` overload; i.e. split the command name and arguments your self.

```
    String[] executeCmd = new String[]{
            "mysqldump",
            "-u", dbUserName",
            "-p", dbPassword,
            "--add-drop-database", 
            "-B", dbName,
            "-r", path
    };
```

---

> How can i automatically detect the path of mysqldump.exe?

I don't think you can. If you can't handle this via the server-side user setting of the `%PATH%` variable, you will have to use a full pathname when invoking the command.

> I don't know how to call mysqldump path form remote server for remote database backup.

You will need to find it out.

Comment: How can i automatically detect the path of mysqldump.exe?I don't know how to call mysqldump path form remote server for remote database backup.if u know pls help me .

Answer (score -1):

Try using 
String executeCmd = "cmd /c mysqldump -u " + dbUserName + " -p" + dbPassword + " --add-drop-database -B " + dbName + " -r " + path;

Comment: Why should he try that?

Comment: Because invoking mysqldump will not be executed directly from java

Comment: And why should that matter?  Basically,you have not identified what the actual problem is, or provided the correct solution to the problem.  The problem is that `exec` is not splitting the command string properly.  What you have suggested won't solve the problem.